# Tagging for the Hitman series

Tags: discussion, tags

With the new Hitman game launching in a couple of weeks, I think it would be good to discuss tags for it ahead of time. This is complicated by the fact that they've decided to call it "Hitman 2", despite that being a game from 2002 - "Hitman 2: Silent Assassin".

With no subtitle, I think the best tag for this new game would be [hitman-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2), or [hitman-2-2018](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2-2018) to be less ambiguous.

There is currently a tag for the original Hitman 2 with 2 questions: [hitman-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2). This could be changed to [hitman-2-silent-assassin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2-silent-assassin) or [hitman-2-2002](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2-2002).

The plain [hitman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman) tag is used for the 2016 game which was ostensibly just called "Hitman", although it was also marketed as "Hitman: The Complete First Season". As they decided against continuing the "series" nomenclature, it would probably be better to move these questions to [hitman-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2016). There's also one question tagged [hitman-beta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-beta) which is just odd.

If the 2016 questions were moved to [hitman-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2016) then I'd suggest making [hitman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman) a synonym for [hitman-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-series).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone ahead and renamed [hitman-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2) to [hitman-2-silent-assassin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2-silent-assassin). I've also added a description to [hitman-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2) to make it clear it's for the 2018 game:

> For the 2018 Hitman 2 game developed by IO Interactive. Not be confused with Hitman 2: Silent Assassin.

Since it's not tied to any games the tag might be deleted and lose the description (honestly not sure), but if we need to create a new description we'll want to indicate it's for the 2018 game.

I've also renamed [hitman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman) to [hitman-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-2016).

I've left [hitman-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-series) alone. We should either reserve the [hitman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman) tag for the first game which hasn't had any questions, or just not use it at all to avoid confusion.

Finally I've gone ahead and approved your edit on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256295/deliver-poisoned-vodka-to-knight), which effectively kills the [hitman-beta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitman-beta) tag as well.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!